# htaccess mask a range of URL's to more readable versions but show content from original URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is a sample of filter URL's on an ecommerce store.

```
http://www.domain.com/showering/showers/filter/alliance
http://www.domain.com/showering/showers/filter/aquaflow
http://www.domain.com/showering/showers/filter/grohe
http://www.domain.com/showering/showers/filter/mira
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I can mask these URL's so they appear like:-

```
http://www.domain.com/alliance-showers
http://www.domain.com/aquaflow-showers
http://www.domain.com/grohe-showers
http://www.domain.com/mira-showers
```

But still display the page content from the `/showering/showers/*` URL's?

I then wish to be able to set the canonical URL's based on these masked URL's.

I've played around with countless variations with little success but here is something I've got so far:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/showering/showers/filter/(alliance)
RewriteRule (.*) /alliance-showers/
```

When this is applied to website, all the images on the Magento store don't load incidentally along with the fact that the URL doesn't change at all.

## Answer to [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557633/htaccess-mask-a-range-of-urls-to-more-readable-versions-but-show-content-from-o/22557751?noredirect=1#comment34333993_22557751)...

.htaccess file is in root or Magento installation. It is the very first rule in file like so:-

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /showering/$2/filter/$1 [L,R]
```

Currently testing with [this URL](http://www.showermania.co.uk/showering/showers/filter/alliance):-

```
http://www.showermania.co.uk/showering/showers/filter/alliance
```

Wanting to show as:-

```
http://www.showermania.co.uk/alliance-showers
```

Current answer has no affect/change on this URL at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^showering/([^/]+)/filter/([^/]+)/?$ /$2-$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - this doesn't appear to be having any affect on the URL currently. Wondering if it is due to placement in the `.htaccess`. Still testing.

Comment: Nope, can't get this to work at all unfortunately. It's not changing the URL's at all regardless of where I put it in the `.htaccess` (loads of other things in the `.htaccess` is in effect).

Comment: See updated rule and make sure this is very first rule in your root .htaccess file. Also tell me all the details about the problem. For which URL it didn't work and location of this .htaccess file?

Comment: Now it's doing something, thanks. Okay so this redirects to '/alliance-showers' whereas I want to just map/mask the URL as so but still show the content at `/showering-showers/filter/alliance`. Thanks.

Comment: ok I took out `R` flag from rule, try now. But I suspect Magento may not like it (you didn't tell about Magento earlier)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right because I've just realised URL changing to `/alliance-showers`  causes redirect loop.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I previously 301 redirected `*-showers` to the filter URL's. Let me disable these redirects :)

Comment: I fixed redirect loop so that leaves: your rule will redirect but removing the `R` stops the redirect but then the URL doesn't change at all.

Comment: yes but you don't want URL to change in browser right?

Comment: Yes I do. I want the URL to look like `domain.com/alliance-showers` but actually display the content on `domain.com/showering/showers/filter/alliance` - thanks.

Comment: Is that possible @anubhava to show the content of a different page but mask the URL? Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything in particular in a Magento .htaccess that would prevent this rule from working. I can see that it should work, it just doesn't in Magento.

Comment: Yes Magento CMS works differently like Wordpress and Joomla. It needs original URI in `REQUEST_URI` variable to work correctly.

Comment: So does a RewriteCond need to be added for that then in Magento in order for this RewriteRule to work?